# Python: CSV module. EscapeChar is messing up the output

Tags: python, csv, escaping

Trying to open a CSV that contains quotes and remove them. I've looked through the documentation for the CSV module for python and it's removing the quotes like I want but the output is trying to escape the comma, which is what I'm trying to avoid. This code:

```
csv.register_dialect('escaped',delimiter=",", escapechar="\\",  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
reader = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb"), skipinitialspace=True)
writer = csv.writer(open(output_file, "wb"), dialect='escaped')

writer.writerows(reader)
```

Results in output like this value1\,value2. How do I get the backslash out of there so it's only the comma in the output. The input files contains a bunch of lines which look this:

```
"Value1,Value2"
```

Comment: Could you please include a few lines of the input file in your question for clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is inline with what the documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) about `QUOTE_NONE`

If all you are trying to do is get rid of the quotes, and given that the input lines are as simple as what you mentioned in the comments, wouldn't this work?

```
with open('input') as in_file, open('output', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write(line.replace('\"', ''))
```

Comment: @Stev0 Must be an issue with the file handles. The above code perfectly reads from a input file and writes to the output file

Comment: I figured it out....I'm ashamed to say I was running a different python file using the same input files. I was just pressing up in the command line and didnt realize it. Working perfectly now that I'm using the write file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using '\7' as the escape char:

```
with open('dmy.tmp','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,escapechar='\7',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    content=[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]
    writer.writerows(content)
```